# LOAD DATA INFILE - Two Default Columns

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I want to load data from a CSV file into a  table in my database. However, the first two columns are an ID (AUTO INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY) and CURRENT DATE (CURRENT DATE ON UPDATE) field. The source file will therefore not have these fields.

How would I get the file to load? The below code doesn't work. I have also tried leaving out id and action_date from the fields in the brackets.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/upliftments//UPLIFTMENTS_20160901.csv'
INTO TABLE database.return_movements
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(   id
,   action_date
,   current_code
,   serial_number
,   new_code
);
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? What's the error message?

Comment: "Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: "
It is looking for 5 columns of data in the data set and there are only 3 columns. So there is a data mismatch. The id field is AUTO INCREMENT, and the action_date field is set to TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: I don't understand, why are the fields in your LOAD query if there are not in the CSV you are loading?

Comment: I added them because having them excluded did not work either. I tried various options. So I'm asking if anyone knows how to load data in a csv file where there are two AUTO POPULATING fields.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you omit them in the LOAD query, they will be auto populated. What was the error you were having then?